# can only access SD card; cant access the internal storage on pc

Tags: internal-storage

i need to delete 3 gigs of "pictures" from my internal storage,it says there is 3 gigs of photos in there but they dont show up in the google file manager and when i connect to pc it only shows the SD card and not the internal storage.

Comment: you should not delete files via MTP this is weak protocol

Comment: On Android for historical reasons a certain part of the internal storage is often calls arcade section. Are you sure you are really see the sd-card and not that part of the internal storage?

Comment: i recommend to delete pictures on the phone itself instead https://android.stackexchange.com/q/232775

Comment: i cant delete the pictures on the phone because they dont show up in the google file manager...

Answer (score 1):

Try going to the settings and then storage and then files to explore if there are any pictures that you can delete.

Comment: the pictures folder is empty in google file manager but it takes up 2.9gb